# macOS: pbcopy not working from PHP calling shell script

Tags: php, shell, clipboard

The command pbcopy works fine in macOS from a terminal. E.g. `pbcopy < file` where the contents of 'file' is put into clipboard. But when I do the same in PHP using either `system()` or the backticks, it is not copied into the clipboard.
I tried even wrapping the command in `sh -c /usr/bin/pbcopy/pbcopy < file`, but to no avail.

What is going wrong ?

```
$tmptext = "this is a very long text afsdfsdfsfsdfsd !!!";
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'clip');
file_put_contents($tmp, $tmptext);
$cmd = "/usr/bin/pbcopy < $tmp";   // does not work from PHP ???
echo nl2br("$cmd\n");
system ($cmd);
```

Comment: Try `$cmd = "/usr/bin/pbcopy < " . $tmp`

Comment: I tried but to no avail. Strictly for PHP it is the same as ````$cmd = "/usr/bin/pbcopy < $tmp";```` . 
Then I tried 
````php -r 'echo "ahdsadkjfdfsdfhsdkfdskfsdfsdfk " > "qqq"; $cmd = "/usr/bin/pbcopy < " . "qqq"; '```` 
from the terminal itself, but it worked neither.

Comment: I don't know why your `pbcopy` is not working, but you could try replacing it with this `/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set the clipboard to (read posix file "/tmp/SOMEFILE" as text)'`

Comment: Thanks. 
That worked ! I only had to confirm to allow System events to do this, but luckily only once.

Comment: FYI, I tried `pbcopy` from Python with the equivalent `os.system()` and it worked fine. I have read of other programs like **GNU** `screen` and `ssh` having difficulty with it and wonder if it is something to do with not having a tty assigned. Maybe that will ring a bell in someone else's head and they can enlighten us!